# TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot project in Javascript. To deploy my commands I have to register them in my index.js file. Here is the structure of my project :

- index.js
- node_modules
- other config files...
- commands
  ∟ command_folder1
  ∟ command1.js
  ∟ command2.js
  ∟ command-folder2
  ∟ command3.js
  ∟ command4.js
  ∟ command-folder...

Something like that.

But I have this error : `TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt`

Here is my index.js file :

```
const {
  Client,
  Collection,
  Intents,
  GatewayIntentBits,
} = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const { token } = require("./config.json");

// Create a new Discord client
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
  ],
});

// Set up a collection to hold your command files
client.commands = new Collection(); // define commands collection here
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync("./commands");

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
  const commandFiles = fs
    .readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`)
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

  for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command); // use client.commands instead of commands
  }
}

// Set up event listeners for when the client is ready and when it receives a command interaction
client.once("ready", async () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

  // Register slash commands
  try {
    const commandData = Array.from(client.commands.values()).map((command) => {
      const data = { ...command };
      if (typeof data.defaultPermission === "boolean") {
        data.defaultPermission = String(data.defaultPermission);
      }
      return data;
    });
    await client.application.commands.set(commandData);
    console.log("Successfully registered application commands.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to register application commands:", error);
  }
});

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName); // use client.commands instead of commands

  if (!command) return;

  try {
    await command.execute(interaction);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    await interaction.reply({
      content: "There was an error while executing this command!",
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  }
});

// Log in to Discord with your bot token
client.login(token);
```

And here is the precise output :

```
Logged in as botname#0000 !
Failed to register application commands: TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at RequestManager.resolveRequest (path\to\file\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1146:26)
    at RequestManager.queueRequest (path\to\file\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1056:46)
    at REST.raw (path\to\file\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1330:32)
    at REST.request (path\to\file\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1321:33)
    at REST.put (path\to\file\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1296:17)
    at ApplicationCommandManager.set (path\to\file\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:173:41)
    at Client.<anonymous> (path\to\file\index.js:48:39)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
```

Edit :

Here is the file that make trouble :

```
const { Discord, PermissionFlagsBits } = require("discord.js");
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require("mongodb");
const uri =
  "urltoconnectdatabase";

const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1,
});

module.exports = {
  name: "createcharacter",
  description: "Create your character",
  options: [
    {
      name: "permission",
      description: "Permission level",
      type: "INTEGER",
      required: true,
      choices: [
        {
          name: "Administrator",
          value: PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],

  async execute(interaction) {
    const userId = interaction.user.id;

    await interaction.reply("What's your character's name?");
    const name = await interaction.channel.awaitMessages({
      filter: (m) => m.author.id === interaction.user.id,
      max: 1,
      time: 30000,
    });

    await interaction.reply("What's your character's house?");
    const house = await interaction.channel.awaitMessages({
      filter: (m) => m.author.id === interaction.user.id,
      max: 1,
      time: 30000,
    });

    await interaction.reply("What's your character's wand?");
    const wand = await interaction.channel.awaitMessages({
      filter: (m) => m.author.id === interaction.user.id,
      max: 1,
      time: 30000,
    });

    await interaction.reply("What's your character's patronus?");
    const patronus = await interaction.channel.awaitMessages({
      filter: (m) => m.author.id === interaction.user.id,
      max: 1,
      time: 30000,
    });

    client.connect().then(
      // success
      () => {
        console.log("Connection successful");

        const collection = client.db("WizardryBot").collection("characters");
        let documentToInsert = {
          userId: userId.toString(),
          name: name.first().content,
          house: house.first().content,
          wand: wand.first().content,
          patronus: patronus.first().content,
          experience: 0,
          money: 0,
          quidditchxp: 0,
        };

        function userOwnCharacter(userId) {
          return collection
            .findOne({ userId: userId })
            .then((result) => Promise.resolve(result !== null))
            .catch((err) => {
              console.error(err);
            });
        }

        userOwnCharacter(userId)
          .then((result) => {
            if (result) {
              console.log("User owns a character");
              return Promise.resolve();
            } else {
              console.log("User does not own any character");

              return collection.insertOne(documentToInsert).then(
                (insertedDocument) => {
                  console.log("Data inserted");
                  // console.log(JSON.stringify(insertedDocument, null, 2));

                  const characterEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle("Character Information")
                    .addField("Name", name.first().content)
                    .addField("House", house.first().content)
                    .addField("Wand", wand.first().content)
                    .addField("Patronus", patronus.first().content)
                    .setColor("#0099ff");

                  interaction.reply({ embeds: [characterEmbed] });

                  return Promise.resolve();
                },
                (reason) => {
                  console.log("Failed to insert document", reason);
                  return Promise.reject(reason);
                }
              );
            }
          })
          .finally(() => {
            console.log("Closing db connection");
            client.close();
          });
      },
      // failure
      (reason) => {
        // Connection failed with reason
        console.log("Connection failed", reason);
      }
    );
  },
};
```

Here is my index.js :

```
const {
  Client,
  Collection,
  Intents,
  GatewayIntentBits,
} = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const { token } = require("./config.json");

// Create a new Discord client
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
  ],
});

// Set up a collection to hold your command files
client.commands = new Collection(); // define commands collection here
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync("./commands");

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
  const commandFiles = fs
    .readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`)
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

  for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command); // use client.commands instead of commands
  }
}

// Set up event listeners for when the client is ready and when it receives a command interaction
client.once("ready", async () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

  // Register slash commands
  try {
    const commandData = Array.from(client.commands.values()).map((command) => {
      const data = { ...command };
      if (typeof data.defaultPermission === "boolean") {
        data.defaultPermission = String(data.defaultPermission);
      }
      // Convert any BigInt values to string
      if (typeof data.id === "bigint") {
        data.id = data.id.toString();
      }
      return data;
    });
    await client.application.commands.set(commandData);
    console.log("Successfully registered application commands.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to register application commands:", error);
  }
});

client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName); // use client.commands instead of commands

  if (!command) return;

  try {
    await command.execute(interaction);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    await interaction.reply({
      content: "There was an error while executing this command!",
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  }
});

// Log in to Discord with your bot token
client.login(token);
```

Comment: One of your command files has a BigInt literal in it.

Comment: this is happening because of a miss configuration in one command. Can you try enabling only one (temporary move the other files)? if the issue still occurs, send the single command file. If the issue disappears, repeat the process for each command until you find the miss configured one.

Comment: You can fix it by converting it to a string: `bigIntValue.toString()`.

Comment: @Androz2091 ok thanks I will try tonight and send the miss configured command file !

Comment: Okay I did it !

Comment: It is a [documented behaviour of `JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#exceptions). A possible workaround is to convert the number to string but this requires the server at the other end to be aware of this change and to be able to handle it correctly.

Comment: And how could I do it ?

Comment: Guys, I still have the same error, I try everything but it doesn't work... Could you help me ? Could I provide you more files like my index.js, something like that ?

Comment: Yes, send your files and ping me

Comment: @Androz2091 I send the index.js file. I don't need to send the other files because I check them one by one and there isn't this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I resolve my error. In my code I didn't need the following part :

```
options: [
    {
      name: "permission",
      description: "Permission level",
      type: "INTEGER",
      required: true,
      choices: [
        {
          name: "Administrator",
          value: PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
```

So I remove it. And now it works !
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score -1):

I faced with this error when I was working with jest tests.

An example when this error happens:

```
expect(BigInt('1.2345')).toBe('1.2345'); // BigInt vs String
```

So if you have conditions check them and redefine them to single type.